# ExtJS why does form.getValues() only return "1", but not "0" for a check box state?

Tags: forms, extjs, checkbox

I have a simple ExtJS 4 (xtype form) inside a window.  It has two fields and a save button.     One of the fields is a string.  That works fine.  If it's blank, getValues() gives me the field blank.   If it's set, I get the value.   However, the check box is different.   If it's checked, I get the value of '1'.   HOWEVER, if I un-check the box (or do not check it), I get no value - the field is not listed in the result of getValues()!   WHY??

```
items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'checkbox',
                        name : 'insuranceVerified',
                        fieldLabel: 'insuranceVerified',
                        inputValue:'1',
                        value:'1'  //does not make a difference
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        name : 'ru',
                        fieldLabel: 'ru'
                    }
]
```

I am catching the save button click event and calling this function in my controller:

```
updateEncounter: function(button) {
        console.log('clicked the Save button');
        var win    = button.up('window'),
            form   = win.down('form'),
            record = form.getRecord(),
            values = form.getValues();

// values properly shows the ru field on the form, but only shows insuranceVerified if it's checked - is not in values if it's unchecked... ??!

            debugger;
        record.set(values);
        this.getEncountersStore().sync();
        win.close();
    }
```

I just figured out something else, though it's not a complete answer for me:
If I change the code above so it get's the form (I assume from the form panel):

```
 form   = win.down('form').getForm(),   // instead of win.down('form')
```

Then, use getFieldValues() on that new object instead of the getValues(), I now have the check box value even if it's un-checked.

```
values = form.getFieldValues();  // instead of getValues()
```

HOWEVER, the value I get back is 'false' (or true), not '0' or '1' like I specified with inputValue:'1'.

Also, I even tried setting a 'value' for the field '1', no difference whether I do that or not for getValues or getFieldValues().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Submit an HTML form with empty checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476426/submit-an-html-form-with-empty-checkboxes)

What do you expect to receive if the checkbox isn't selected? You specified the value being sent if it is checked..

Here another solution:
[How come checkbox state is not always passed along to PHP script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520952/how-come-checkbox-state-is-not-always-passed-along-to-php-script)

Comment: Well, in the case of getFieldValues() I receive true if it's checked, false if it's not checked.     What I really want is '1' if it's checked and 0 if it's not checked.    So according to the links you provided, on my PHP back end, i would have to assume the field is '0' unless it is sent?    I understand the HTML/PHP issues in those links, but it seems like ExtJS should be marking the field dirty and shouldn't unchecked be a value in ExtJS, a value of false, 0, NO, etc. that I can then send to the server to update the DB?

Comment: OK, after posting my last comment, I found the answer, simply add a property of:   uncheckedValue:'0'   to the check box definition!

Answer (score 9):

This works for me. Hope to help with

```
{
   xtype: 'checkbox',
   boxLabel: modelFields[i].label,
   name: modelFields[i].name,
   //magic!
   inputValue: 1,
   uncheckedValue: 0
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use

```
var answer1IsCorrect = Ext.getCmp('Answer1RadioButton').checked ? 1 : 0;
```

insted of `true` or `false`