# How do I remove checkbox values from a SESSION after POST?

Tags: php

I'm trying to figure out a way to remove checkbox values from a `SESSION`.

I have a form with a checkbox array, among other fields. When the form is submitted, the field values are stored in a `SESSION`, so that if the user refreshes the page, the values stick.

However, if they then **uncheck** the checkboxes and re-submit the form, the checkbox values still stick because the checkbox name never gets posted in the `POST` array, so I don't know which values to `unset()`

I'm trying to come up with a way to look into the `SESSION` and remove anything that's not in `POST`.

This is what I have so far, but it's just not working right because it's checking for a non-existent value in `POST`. I think it's backwards, but I haven't been able to figure out how to reverse it.

```php
foreach ($_POST as $post_key => $post_value) {
    if (is_array($post_value)) {
        $result = array_diff($_SESSION[$this->session], $_POST[$post_key]);
        foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
            if (($k = array_search($value, $_SESSION[$this->session])) !== false) {
                unset($_SESSION[$this->session][$k]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The POST checkbox array is basically

```
Array
(
    [food] => Array
        (
            [0] => steak
            [1] => chicken
        )

    [submit] => Submit
)
```

Of course, when no checkboxes are checked, it looks like this, so I don't know what to `unset()`

```
Array
(
    [submit] => Submit
)
```

Comment: Here is one approach: [POST unchecked HTML checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809494/post-unchecked-html-checkboxes). Many [variations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520952/how-come-checkbox-state-is-not-always-passed-along-to-php-script) of that asked here.

Comment: @ficuscr Thanks, this led me to the answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I did. I created a `hidden` element that contains all of the checkbox array values and put that into the form.

```html
<input type="hidden" name="food_values" value="steak,chicken,fish">
```

Upon `POST`, I explode that hidden element into an array: `$hidden_checkbox_values`.

I then take each `$_POST['food']` checkbox value and put it into the `SESSION`.

I then `array_diff()` the `$hidden_checkbox_values` array against the `$_POST['food']` array. If a value is in `$hidden_checkbox_values` but not in `$_POST['food']`, I remove it from the `SESSION` as it wasn't ticked when the form was submitted.

If there are no values in the POST array, then all checkboxes were unchecked, and I remove all checkbox values from the `SESSION`.

```php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    // get all checkbox values from the hidden element and put them into an array
    $hidden_checkbox_values = explode(',', $_POST['food_values']);

    if (isset($_POST['food'])) {
        if (isset($_SESSION['myForm']))
        {
            // add all POSTed checkbox values to the session
            foreach ($_POST['food'] as $key => $value) {
                if (!in_array($value, $_SESSION['myForm'])) {
                    $_SESSION['myForm'][] = $value;
                }
            }

            // if a value from our values array is NOT in our POST array, remove it from the session
            $clean1 = array_diff($_POST['food'], $hidden_checkbox_values);
            $clean2 = array_diff($hidden_checkbox_values, $_POST['food']);
            $output = array_merge($clean1, $clean2);
            foreach ($output as $value) {
                foreach ($_SESSION['myForm'] as $skey => $svalue) {
                    if ($svalue == $value) {
                        unset($_SESSION['myForm'][$skey]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        // all checkboxes were unchecked, remove all checkbox values from the session
        foreach ($hidden_checkbox_values as $value) {
            foreach ($_SESSION['myForm'] as $skey => $svalue) {
                if ($svalue == $value) {
                    unset($_SESSION['myForm'][$skey]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```